# Flutter Provider showing results ONLY after Hot Reload

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I am a beginner, and I am building an app following a tutorial using provider. The logic is that, when You click the "Categories" widget, it should lead you to a page with products in that category. The logic works as expected except I have to first refresh the code for results to show. I frankly do not know what I am doing wrong.

From the Homepage, the Categories widget is rendered using a listview builder

```
Container(
                height: 75,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: categoryProvider.categories.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () async {
                        await productProvider.loadProductsByCategory(
                            categoryName:
                                categoryProvider.categories[index].name);
                        changeScreen(
                            context,
                            CategoryScreen(
                                categoryModel:
                                    categoryProvider.categories[index]));
                      },
                      child: CategoriesWidget(
                          category: categoryProvider.categories[index]),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
```

### Main.Dart

I am listening to providers like this

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: AppProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: UserProvider.initialize()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: CategoryProvider.initialize()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: MarketProvider.initialize()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: ProductProvider.initialize()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Akatale',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          home: ScreenController())));
}

class ScreenController extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final auth = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);

    switch (auth.status) {
      case Status.Uninitialized:
        return Loading();
      case Status.UnAuthenticated:
      case Status.Authenticating:
        return SignInScreen();
      case Status.Authenticated:
        return MainScreen();
      default:
        return SignInScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

### Product Service

With this, I fetch products from firestore by the name of the category and add them to a List

```
class ProductService extends ChangeNotifier {
  String collection = "products";
  Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;


  Future<List<ProductModel>> getProductsByCategory({String category}) async {
    List<ProductModel> products = [];
    _firestore
        .collection(collection)
        .where("category", isEqualTo: category)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((result) {
      for (DocumentSnapshot product in result.documents) {
        products.add(ProductModel.fromSnapshot(product));
      }
    });
    return products;
  }
}
```

### Product Provider

Here I have public methods to be called in widgets

```
class ProductProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  ProductService _productService = ProductService();
  List<ProductModel> products = [];
  List<ProductModel> productsByCategory = [];


  ProductProvider.initialize() {
    _loadProducts();
   
  }

  //Private method Load products to List
  Future _loadProducts() async {
    products = await _productService.getProducts();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  //public method to Load products to List by category
  Future loadProductsByCategory({String categoryName}) async {

    productsByCategory =
        await _productService.getProductsByCategory(category: categoryName);

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

### Categories Page

This is where products are rendered based on the chosen category

```
class CategoryScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final CategoryModel categoryModel;

  const CategoryScreen({Key key, this.categoryModel}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productProvider = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: ListView(
        children: [
          Text(categoryModel.name),
          Column(
            children: productProvider.productsByCategory.map((item) {
              return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    //Load details page
                  },
                  child: ProductWidget(
                    product: item,
                  ));
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

**A blank page is displayed**
[image: Categories page]

**But on hitting Hot reload, the products appear**
[image]

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but by skimming over your code I did not find a Widget listening to ProductProvider

Comment: You are right. If what I think is what You meant, I have edited the question to add that. I am doing that in the main.dart file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getProductsByCategory` in your `ProductsService` you are not awaiting `getDocuments`.
So while the documents will get loaded it already calls notifyListeners in the model before it is actually done loading them.
And thus when you rebuild using hotreload they show up

To fix this simply await the getDocuments in the service